# partitioning old NTFS hdd

Tags: partition, disk, fdisk

I am using Ubuntu 18.4 and i have a 4 disk NAS. I found an old hdd that i thought i'd install for a bit of extra space. When i run fdisk -l the disk is listed as follows

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe142a378

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT1
```

Try as i might to use fdisk to delete and create a new partition of type 83 (Linux). When i run fdisk -l it never changes from HPFS/NTFS/exFAT1 type 7.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I'm not really the guy to answer this sort of question, but for me if I don't have anything on the drive I wish to keep, I either write 0s to the drive or do ATA secure erase. That always clears everything.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'll try anything so i'll give that a go now.

Comment: Show what you did within `fdisk`. Did you `w`rite your actions to disk?

Comment: @RudiC yes i did a write

Comment: how many partitions do you want and how big do you want them to be

Comment: 1 partition, the whole disk